# Updating Modules in VBA (Word)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got for example Module1, Module2 and some UserForms in Normal. I've got modules and forms save d to files too, Module1.bas and Module2.bas, etc. During running macro (procedure in Macro1) I check if Module1 version in Normal is the same as in file Module1.bas, if it is different I would like to remove Module1 and Module2. Problem is that I can't remove Module1 because I call procedure from that Module. Module1 is removed when macro stops working.

```
Private Function RemoveModulesAndForms() As Boolean

Dim component As Object
Dim componentName As String
Dim isComponentRemoved As Boolean
Dim notRemoved() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim isAllRemoved As Boolean
Dim prompt As String
Dim caption_ As String

i = -1
isAllRemoved = True
For Each component In Application.Templates("Normal.dotm").VBProject.VBComponents
    componentName = component.name
    DoEvents
    If componentName <> "ThisDocument" Then
        Application.Templates("Normal.dotm").VBProject.VBComponents.Remove component
        
        isComponentRemoved = Not CheckIfComponentExist(componentName)

        If isComponentRemoved = False Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve notRemoved(i)
            notRemoved(i) = componentName
            isAllRemoved = False
        End If
    End If
Next

prompt = "Components not removed: " + Join(notRemoved, ",")
If isAllRemoved = False Then
    MsgBox prompt, vbCritical
End If
RemoveModulesAndForms = isAllRemoved
End Function
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the code that does the checking in Module 3?  The code in Module 3 should be called before you call code elsewhere probably using autorun so that it is the first code that is run when a document is opened.

Comment: I have version of macro in Module1, when I put checking version in Module3, I will have to compare version of Module1 in Normal and version of file Module1, so I will have to call Module1, so it won't be posible remove Module1, maybe Calling Module1 is in the memory (some reference to that module?)